# Why doesnt my stack trace include the page that it was originally called from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

As I understand asp.net exceptions. If I have a page that calls some code that in turns calls another bit of code. If the last bit of code (say its in a different dll) throws an exception, and its handled nowhere then I should get the page throw an error out on a YSOD that has the stack trace which shows in reverse chronological order what happened. So i will get at the bottom of the stack trace the first bit of code that was executed then above it the next flowing all the way to the top where is the actual error happened.

This in mind I have an application that is not showing the aspx page in the stack trace. Also its not showing the usual initial calls to the asp.net stack like:

> at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp,
>   Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   Community.Support.BasePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Projects\Unilever\BinaryFiles\Support\BasePage.cs:line 389 at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I cant really see why. The only hint im getting is that reflection is being used and I'm wondering is this why?

Comment: it depends on several aspects... for example if the exception occurs on a different thread then you won't get the "caller" since it isn't even occuring on the same stack (each thread has its very own stack) !

Comment: The stack trace gets reset if you re-throw an exception (or throw a new exception without preserving the existing stack in `InnerException`).

Comment: Isn't `Community.Support.BasePage` the actual aspx page? Or it could even be a class which derives from Web.UI.Page; your actual aspx page derives from this class.

Comment: The base page is probably doing a `throw ex;` at line 389. Go take a look at that line to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a BasePage class, a great way to get detailed information is to override the OnError method; this method fires for all unhandled errors in the page. Then, collect information about the page and add it to the error, or add it to the logged statement.

HTH.